# How I print an array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays

In C++ I have the code below and I wanted to make the same in Python.

```
#include iostream
using namespace std;

int main()

{

    int tab[10][10], m, n, i, j;

    cout << "\n number of rows n = ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "\n number of columns m = ";
    cin >>m;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<m; j++)
        {
            cout << "\n tab[" << i << "][" << j << "] = ";
            cin >> tab[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<m; j++)
            cout << "\t\t" << tab[i][j];
            cout << "\n\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried this:

```
def main():
    pass
    tab = []
    m = input ("Numbers of rows: ")
    n = input ("Numbers of columns: ")
    for i in xrange(m):
        for j in xrange(n):
            print tab[i:j], "= "
            arr = input ("tab[i:j]")
            print arr
```

I do not know to print in a for loop `tab[i][j] = "value input from keyboard"`

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Stack overflow is not a code translation service.

Comment: It's really easy just write this code with python and your done!

Comment: `cout` and `cin` is a C++ struff, there is no equivalent in Python because Pyhton is a high level language.

Comment: Did you also want to include the buffer overrun bug too? That might be a bit difficult in Python.

Answer (score 1):

there is no such implementation like iostreams in python. Nor are there multidimensional arrays.
You would use 
     r = raw_input("Text: ")

to request the user's parameter.

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python

 # untested python code!

 n = int(raw_input("number of rows, n = "))
 m = int(raw_input("number of cols, m = "))

 tab = [[0]*n for i in xrange(m)] # generates [[0, 0, .. 0][0, 0, .. 0]...[0, .., 0]]

 for i in range(0, n):
     for j in range(0, m):
        tab[i][j] = int(raw_input("tab[%d][%d] = "%(i, j) ))

 for i in range(0, n):
     for j in range(0, m):
        print "\t\t%d" % tab[i][j]
     print "\n"
```

Would suggest to use something like numpy for arrays. There are better solutions like hashs or dictionaries.

**Edit**:
As i supposed above: you need to initialize the array first by

```
tab = [[0]*n for i in xrange(m)]
```

After this initialization, by writing

```
print tab
```

the whole structure will be shown. A single element is shown by calling it like:

```
print tab[i][j]
```

Using the colon (:) you specifiy a range, ***tab[i][j] != tab[i:j]***

You can still print a row with

```
print tab[i]  # <-- only the first array in the array
print tab[i][j] # <-- only the element j. element in the i. array
```

Cheers.

Comment: Why don't you use `n` and `m` to dynamically size the `tab` list rather than hardcoding to 10?

Comment: `m` and `n` need to be converted to int for use in `range()`, but otherwise it's close enough to the OP's C++ version.